# Generate Parentheses in LeetCode

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on solving problem [Generate Parentheses on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/). My first thought was that the `n+1`th pair of parentheses could be deduced from `n`th pair of parentheses. Saying, if we use `e` as the situation of `n`th, and I thought the `n+1`th will be one of the following situation:

- `(` + `e` + `)`
- `()` + `e`
- `e` + `()`

And I came up with the following code.

```
public class Solution {
    public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        HashSet<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> rsult = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (n == 0) {
            temp.add("");
            return new ArrayList<String>(temp);
        }

        temp.add("()");

        if (n == 1) {

            return new ArrayList<String>(temp);
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result.removeAll(temp);
            for (String e : temp) {
                if (!result.contains("(" + e + ")")) {
                    result.add("(" + e + ")");
                }

                if (!result.contains("()" + e)) {
                    result.add("()" + e);
                }

                if (!result.contains(e + "()")) {
                    result.add(e + "()");
                }

            }

            temp.clear();
            temp.addAll(result);
        }
        rsult = new ArrayList<String>(result);
        Collections.sort(rsult);
        return rsult;
    }
}
```

However, when I submitted the code, I found that I still missed some cases when the `n+1` is even. So I updated my code as below.

```
public class Solution {
    public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        HashSet<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> rsult = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (n == 0) {
            temp.add("");
            return new ArrayList<String>(temp);
        }

        temp.add("()");

        if (n == 1) {

            return new ArrayList<String>(temp);
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result.removeAll(temp);
            for (String e : temp) {
                if (!result.contains("(" + e + ")")) {
                    result.add("(" + e + ")");
                }

                if (!result.contains("()" + e)) {
                    result.add("()" + e);
                }

                if (!result.contains(e + "()")) {
                    result.add(e + "()");
                }

                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    String dblprt = new String();
                    for(int j = 0; j< i/2;j++) {
                        dblprt = "(" + dblprt + ")";
                    }
                    dblprt = dblprt + dblprt ;
                    if (!result.contains(dblprt)) {
                        result.add(dblprt);
                    }
                }
            }

            temp.clear();
            temp.addAll(result);
        }
        rsult = new ArrayList<String>(result);
        Collections.sort(rsult);
        return rsult;
    }
}
```

Still, the test cases failed. So I'm confused. Why doesn't my way work? Am I still missing some cases?

Comment: I don't know what's the problem in this snippet but you're stressing yourself. This is basically a 3 line DFS problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't my way work? Am I still missing some cases?

Consider the parentheses `(())(())`, the only way for this to have come from your algorithm is if `e = ())(()`, and then `(` + `e` + `)` but in that case `e` is not a well-formed parentheses so `e` never existed and you have missed a case.

**EDIT**: it would seem that your second revision solves cases such as `()()`, `(())(())`, `((()))((()))` but what about `(()())(()())`, or `(()())()(())`?